A young woman sneaks into a kids classroom, and draws her insides on her body
The movie is about a young boy, and probably the relationship between him, his dad and the dads new girlfriend, however I'm not sure if the young woman is the dads girlfriend, or just a girl traveling through town.
The boy, as I remember, dislikes the woman at first. If the dad and the lady are a thing, then this might be the reason he dislikes her. But this changes later on, and as I recall, they become good friends. 
Shes a bubbly playful type of girl. Pretty sure she is blond and slim, with shoulder long hair. 
The scene i remember from the movie: at one point in the movie, when the boy doesn't dislike her anymore, they lure the teacher out and while the teacher-lady is out of the classroom, the woman sneaks in from the window, takes off her clothes (she has a skin colored bathing suit on) and draws her reproductive system onto her body/skinsuit and gives the class a real sex-ed class or something. 
There has to have been some complaints from either the class as a whole, or from the boy alone, that the sex-ed at this school is lacking. I think the school has been confronted with this, and been against giving a more thorough class in this subject. This is the reason for her sneaking in, and the whole scene is a stressing one, as the teacher is trying to get back in.  
The mood of the movie is light, but not without feeling. 
If I were to guess, the movie is from late 80s or early 90s. 
I think its american. 
I thought the girl might have been Daryl Hannah, or Patricia Arquette or something. But I cant find the movie in their Imdb-movie list. 
I've tried google, but I end up with bathing suits and news about schools. 

Sounds like Milk Money from 1994.

Young Frank and his pals get an idea for the ultimate in excitement. They decide to pool their savings, bicycle to the nearby Big City, and hire some woman of the streets to strip for them. Things do not work out that simply, but they do meet V, a Hooker With A Heart Of Gold, who ends up giving them a ride home. Soon she is living in Frank's treehouse, unbeknownst to Frank's widowed father Tom, who thinks she is one of Frank's teachers. Soon, however, the evil Waltzer comes looking for V.

The hooker is Melanie Griffith and the dad is Ed Harris. And at some point: 

At school, Frank flunks a biology test about sex education and must give his class an oral presentation. He decides to use V as a mannequin and through a ruse distracts his teacher long enough to draw a relatively accurate female reproductive system on her skin-colored bodysuit.

Here's the beginning of that scene:




I've seen this film and agree, it seems to fit.
